# Build file path & expand wildcard from variables

Tags: bash

```
input_dir="~/path/to/dir/"
file_ext=".fastq.gz"
input_path="${input_dir}*${file_ext}"

echo "$input_path"
# returns: ~/path/to/dir/*.fastq.gz

for f in "$input_path" ; do echo "$f" ; done

# returns: ~/path/to/dir/*.fastq.gz
```

I was expecting a list of all files with the extension .fastq.gz.

Comment: If the `*` is within double quotes then it becomes literal, so that itself needs to be unquoted.

Comment: Glob characters e.g. `~` and `*` must be outside the quotes.

Comment: @anubhava: I'm being picky.  You are correct in that Tilde Expansion only occurs if `~` is unquoted, but  `~` is not a glob character.  See `man bash` and search for "Tilde Expansion", also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01.    On Linux, see also `man 7 glob`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't store a glob pattern without losing information about which elements are and aren't intended to be quoted. Thus, two separate variables need to be used for the prefix and the suffix *at glob expansion time*, with the glob itself expanded unquoted between them:

```
input_dir=~/path/to/dir/ # ~ must not be in quotes; use $HOME if you want to quote it
file_ext=".fastq.gz"
for f in "${input_dir}"/*"${file_ext}"; do
  echo "Found $f"
done
```

Note the pattern -- `"$prefix"/*"$suffix"` -- with both expansions within quotes; this prevents those expanded portions from themselves being subject to string-splitting or glob expansion.

---

If you want to store a directive controlling how files are identified in a shell variable, consider an array storing `find` arguments:

```
# this is an array variable, with one entry per argument
find_args=( ~/path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -name '*.fastq.gz' )

while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  printf 'Found %q\n' "$filename"
done < <(find "${find_args[@]}" -print0)
```

---

Another option is to perform the expansion early on, and store its result in an array variable, iterating over the contents of that variable in your `for` loop:

```
input_dir=~/path/to/dir
file_ext=.fastq.gz
input_files=( "$input_dir"/*"$file_ext" )

for f in "${input_files[@]}"; do
  printf 'Found %q\n' "$f"
done
```

---

By the way -- be aware that if your glob expression matches no files, the glob will by default evaluate to the expression itself. It may thus be wise to check for whether your `$f` *actually exists*, to handle this case, or to enable the `nullglob` shell option (which disables this behavior) at the top of your script.

Thus:

```
 shopt -s nullglob # this prevents a non-matching glob from evaluating to itself
```

...or...

```
for f in "$input_dir"/*"$file_ext"; do
  # lack of quotes acceptable here because [[ ]] suppresses string-splitting and globbing
  [[ -e $f || -L $f ]] || { printf '%s\n' "$f not found" >&2; continue; }
  printf 'Found %q\n' "$f"
done
```

Comment: ...which I very much don't. It's hard enough using `eval` in a correct and safe manner even when one has a solid handle on the language.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Is there an advantage to using `"${var}"` over `"$var"`? I've often wondered this.

Comment: Dang - I was waaay off. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @lll, no advantage for simple variables except when concatenating their contents with characters that are eligible to be variable name components. In the example here, `for f in "$input_dir"/*"$file_ext"` would be every bit as correct.

Comment: `{ }` are required a lot more in the c shell (csh) where additional expansions are available.  Some code (and coders) dating back to when csh was popular has migrated but retained the `{ }` folklore.